# How to sort SET in apex

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app

I have a `set<Times>` in my apex code which i want to sort. My time comes like
12:00, 13:00,8:00,11:00. How can i sort the set in ascending order?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't sort a Set, as Sets are, by definition, *unordered*. Convert it to a List first:

```
List<Time> timeList = new List<Time>(timeSet);
timeList.sort();
```